# Jenkins -AAPT2 - Daemon startup failed

Tags: android, jenkins, ionic-framework, jenkins-pipeline, aapt2

I'm currently working on automating the APK build process, setting up a Jenkins pipeline for the project. My Jenkins is on a Docker container that has npm, Ionic, OpenJDK, Android SDK, and Gradle installed.
Our team is using Capacitor in the project. This is my "Build APK" stage in my pipeline

```
 stage('Build APK') {
         sh 'npm run build'
         sh 'npx capacitor sync android'
         sh 'npx capacitor build android --keystorepath /keyfiles/<filename>.jks --keystorealias <alias> --keystorepass <pass> --keystorealiaspass <pass> --androidreleasetype APK'
```

However, I'm encountering an error in the Jenkins console:

```
        > Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
        > Task :capacitor-google-maps:extractReleaseAnnotations
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
        > Multiple task action failures occurred:
        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
        > AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.1-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
        > AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.1-7984345-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
        > AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.1-7984345-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Tried searching on google and stackoverflow, but still issue exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by switching to a different base image of Jenkins. I initially used the Alpine image (`FROM docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:alpine`) and then changed it to the latest version (`FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest`), which successfully resolved the problem.